# Property of an integral that vanishes

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $x\in[a,b)$. Suppose $$ \lim_{x\to b^-} \int_a^x f(u) du =0 ~.$$ Does this imply that

$$ \lim_{x\to b^-}  \int_a^x g(u)f(u) du =0 ? $$

Answer (score 1):

No. To see it, take the function $g$ equal to $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not
$$\lim_{x\to 2\pi ^-} \int_\pi^x \cos (u) du =0 $$
but 
$$\lim_{x\to 2\pi ^-} \int_\pi^x u \cos (u) du =2 $$

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not. Easy counterexample:

$a=0,b=2\pi$,f(u)=sin(u),g(u)=sin(u)$

$\lim_{x\to b^-}\int_a^xf(u)du=\lim_{x\to 2\pi^-}\int_0^xsin(u)du=\lim_{x\to 2\pi^-}(-cos(x)+cos(0))=-cos(2\pi)+cos(0)=-1+1=0$

$\lim_{x\to b^-}\int_a^xf(u)g(u)du=\lim_{x\to 2\pi^-}\int_0^xsin(u)sin(u)du=\lim_{x\to 2\pi^-}(x/2-1/4sin[2x]-(0/2-1/4sin[0]))=2\pi/2-1/4sin[4\pi]-(0/2-1/4sin[0])=\pi$